# JSF 2 h:dataTable with inputText values binded to List. Values not updating

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to display the data from a List contained in a bean via a datatable, and have actions performed by code as the user types. It initially displays ok, and changes to the List are reflected in UI.

My issue is that values entered into the inputText are ignored. Tried looking for solutions, I've tried checking the List as the values changed, and also tried to check without the ajax in case that was the issue (no change). Have tried using session and view scoped bean without luck. Tried wrapping the Strings in a POJO.

Going crazy here. Feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any idea?

```
        <h:dataTable id="multioptionanswers"
            value="#{multiTextBean.texts}" var="texts">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Enter Values"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <h:inputText value="#{texts}" immediate="true">
                        <f:ajax event="blur" execute=":addgroup"
                        render=":addgroup"
                        listener="#{multiTextBean.update}" />
                </h:inputText>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

**addgroup is a panel group that the data table resides in.

Comment: Is your 'h:datatable' wrapped in an 'h:form' attribute?

Comment: what component does the id "addgroup" belong to?

Comment: Thomas Schmidt --> its wrapped in a panelgroup only. Originally it was in a form within the panelgroup, but this stopped the ajax from being called. Not sure why, I know a form within a form is bad. After I removed the form, the ajax features where called.

Comment: tt_dev  --> addgroup resides directly under h:body

Comment: I've replaced the panelgroup with a form, no noticeable change in behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, needed change to how the inputtext read the data. Solution below in case it helps someone :

```
<h:dataTable id="multioptionanswers" binding="#{table}"
                value="#{multiTextBean.texts}" var="texts">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Enter Values"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:inputText 
                        value="#{multiTextBean.texts[table.rowIndex]}">
                        <f:ajax event="blur" execute=":addgroup"     render=":addgroup"
                        listener="#{multiTextBean.update}" />
                </h:inputText>    
            </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
```